# How do I echo the contents of 2 different arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

The question may have been unclear, but it requires a bit of explaining, so here goes:

I have 2 arrays: `$friendsarr` and `$friendunamearr`. `$friendarr` holds the ID's of the users on the user's friends list, and `$friendunamearr` holds their username. I've already echoed their usernames using the following code:

```
$funameimp = implode('<br />', $friendunamearr);
echo($funameimp);
```

But I want to turn these into links. For example:

```
echo('<a href="../../profile?id=' . $somebodysID . '>' . $funameimp . '</a>');
```

I heard something about "foreach," but I have no idea what to do.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear and can you please show us what are the structure of the arrays? print_r($array) and add them to the question

Comment: did you get the 2 array from a db? I suspect doing a query with a join in the first place would make this a whole lot easier

Comment: @AliTrixx you mean print_r($friendarr) and print_r($friendunamearr)

Comment: I'm actually not really sure what I'm doing with these arrays as I don't fully understand them yet. I just need to print each id into it's own link with the username array as the link text.

Comment: I read your variable as `f* you name imp` :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arrays are keyed the same you can do it like this:

```
foreach ($friendarr as $key => $value){
    echo '<a href="../../profile?id=' . $value . '>' . $friendunamearr[$key] . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I put the id in the href attribute of an A tag?

Comment: $friendarr contains the ids, right? You're looping through that array and each time the id is stored in the variable $value, so you have id = $value in your anchor tag.

Comment: 2 issues:
1. It only displays one of the friends (I have 2 on the list)
2. When I click on "rach667," it takes me to "website.com/profile?id=3%3EConner%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20href=". Conner is the other friend. Conner's ID is 2, and Rach667's id is 3.

Comment: I don't know what your arrays are like. If you post your arrays, it would be a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: Do you want me to var_dump them or something? I'm still kind of new to this, so please bear with me

Comment: You could click on edit under your answer and either post a var_dump, or you could post something like `$friendarr = array(1, 2, 3,);` If your array just has ids, why is it showing all that other stuff? "3%3EConner%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20"

Comment: Oh, well, the code is just `$friendsarr = array();`
And the var_dump result is: array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31549/discussion-between-dubstaphone-and-pe-de-leao)

Comment: Sorry, but my wife is waiting for dinner, but if your array has just 2 and 3, where did all that other stuff come from? You achor tags should have ../profil?id=2, etc.

Comment: Do I need to implode them like this? `implode('', $array);`

Comment: Problem solved. Instead of `'<a href="../../profile?id=' . $value . '>' . $friendunamearr[$key] . '</a><br />'`, it needed to be `'<a href="../../profile?id=' . $value . '">' . $friendunamearr[$key] . '</a><br />'` with the double quote before the >.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Sorry about the typo.